# uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token in Chrome in jquery replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
jQuery('div#top').replaceWith('<div id="top">

</div>')
```

Chrome says uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token in the first line. I dont know whats the error here. I am just trying to replace the top div.

FYI -- I am replacing the whole data of div top with mine. I am placing a lot of div`s inside  top which I havent pasted here.

Comment: `uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token` ? anything after that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript strings can't span across multiple lines. You either have to add newline escape sequences:

```
jQuery('div#top').replaceWith('<div id="top">\n\n</div>')
```

Or add backslashes at the end of each line:

```
jQuery('div#top').replaceWith('<div id="top">\
\
</div>')
```

Or just use `.html()` (assuming you weren't trying to get rid of any attributes on that element):

```
jQuery('div#top').html('')
```

Or `.empty()`:

```
jQuery('div#top').empty()
```

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to get rid of all the elements inside #top